# Updating a database periodically with Java

Tags: java

I would like to perform updates to a MySQL database using two separate classes (that do different things) -- one doing so every 10 seconds, and the second every minute. I have a few gaps in my Java knowledge and I'm wondering what the best way to achieve it is.

Importantly, if connectivity to the database is lost, I need reconnection attempts to occur indefinitely, and I'm guessing the use of Prepared Statements will make queries more efficient. Should the connection to the database be left open all the time or closed between the updates being run? Maybe I also need to think about clearing objects/resources out of memory if the class instances are going to be run indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question "how to run java class at some specific interval?"

You can use [quartz triggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson01.html) to run java class at time interval.

Second Question: "what if conn is lost?"

Check in class that runs at time interval for connection if its open then dont attempt to connect and if lost then first connect to db and then update the db.

Third question: "Should the connection left open every time?"

If you wanna do update with very small time gap then i think yes you should keep it open.but not sure about it. May be you should try it keeping open.

Comment: For a multi-user database, you're generally better off closing the connection as soon as you're not actively communicating with the database.  That will allow the database's resources to be freed up for other uses.  Connection pooling on the client system should minimize the cost of reconnecting.

Comment: Yes Connection Pooling can be the solution.

Comment: What advantage do quartz triggers have over using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor::scheduleAtFixedRate?

Comment: Quartz will allow you to schedule jobs in a cron like fashion. So Quartz is useful, but might be a bit of overkill depending on what you need.

Comment: The tasks take place inside an application that already runs as a service so I think Quartz is probably not necessary.

Comment: if you want to schedule a recurring task then only you should use Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the database connection open but do noty try to manage the open connection yourself. Use a connection pooling library like [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). It allows to specify a **validationQuery** which technically a very simple SELECT request that is executed before the actual statement for validating if the connection is still alive. In my application this works rock solid (one app that runs 24/7; queries about every minute).

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure how the validation query would help though if it's just being run each time my regular queries run, those will determine if the database connectivity is available in themselves, won't they?

Comment: If you prefer that your SQL query fails and you have to redo it instead of letting that handle DBCP by the validation query internally - well that's your choice.

Comment: Well, in this situation the data that's getting written to the database is only valid for a short time (server monitoring metrics e.g. CPU load) so I am more worried about re-establishing the connection.